# why i get response before request status in command prompt, although i have got right output in postman?

Tags: node.js

[image: cmd]
[image: cmd ss2]
[image: postman response]

in cmd ss2, why console.log r shown before request GET /api/categories 200 334.691 ms - 1078??

here, i want to get all categories, my code runs good but i cannot understand command prompt part??

category controller-->

```
exports.list=(req,res)=>{
    //console.log(req);
    Category.find().exec((err,data)=>{
        if(err)
        {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: errorHandler(err)
            })
        }
       let r=res.json(data);
       console.log(r);  
       return r;
    })
}
```

category route-->

```
const express=require('express')
const router=express.Router()//new router object
const{ create,categoryById,read,update,remove,list }=require('../controllers/category');
const{ requireSignin, isAuth, isAdmin }=require('../controllers/auth');
//const {userSignupValidator}= require('../validator');
const{ userById }=require('../controllers/user');

router.get("/category/:categoryId",read);

router.post("/category/create/:userId",requireSignin,isAuth,isAdmin,create);//sir told requireSignin,isAuth,isAdmin, as mw and create as only method

router.put("/category/:categoryId/:userId",requireSignin,isAuth,isAdmin,update);

router.delete("/category/:categoryId/:userId",requireSignin,isAuth,isAdmin,remove);

router.get("/categories",list);

router.param("categoryId",categoryById);

router.param("userId",userById);


module.exports=router;
```